# How can improve this code (fixed js upload and preview)?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

How can I improve this code (fixed JavaScript upload and preview)?

I have 7 image fields that I need to upload, but is it the case that I could change my code so it uses a `for` loop or some other easier methods?

Because when user choose the photo, I want to preview the photo when user clicks submit before.

This is my JavaScript code:

```js
function displayImage1(e){
  if(e.files[0]){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
      document.querySelector('#logodisplay1').setAttribute('src',e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[0]);
  }
}
function triggerClick2(){
  document.querySelector('#logo2').click();
}

function displayImage2(e){
  if(e.files[0]){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
      document.querySelector('#logodisplay2').setAttribute('src',e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[0]);
  }
}
function triggerClick3(){
  document.querySelector('#logo3').click();
}

function displayImage3(e){
  if(e.files[0]){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
      document.querySelector('#logodisplay3').setAttribute('src',e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[0]);
  }
}
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<div>
    <img class="view" id="logodisplay" onclick="triggerClick1()" name="logodisplay1" src="/themes/Okmaster/img/image_default.png" width="182" height="182">
    <input type="file" style="display:none" id="logo1" name="logo1" onchange="displayImage1(this)" required="required">
</div>
<div>
    <img class="view" id="logodisplay" onclick="triggerClick2()" name="logodisplay2" src="/themes/Okmaster/img/image_default.png" width="182" height="182">
    <input type="file" style="display:none" id="logo2" name="logo2" onchange="displayImage2(this)" required="required">
</div>
<div>
    <img class="view" id="logodisplay" onclick="triggerClick3()" name="logodisplay3" src="/themes/Okmaster/img/image_default.png" width="182" height="182">
    <input type="file" style="display:none" id="logo3" name="logo3" onchange="displayImage3(this)" required="required">
</div>
```

And when I was click triggerClick2(), it would get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
at FileReader.reader.onload

where has problem it?

Comment: Your "php code" is actually just HTML. There's no backend code here in play. You could look at a for loop in Javascript to make these fields.

Comment: You're using the same ID for each `<img>`. Don't do that